# C# WPF: Удаляются ли бинды на метод элемента списка при его удалении?

Tags: c#, wpf

Вопрос довольно простой, но я не смог найти информацию об этом

У меня есть `ListView` с 250+ элементов.

Элементы добавляются динамически, в цикле, где на **двойное нажатие по элементу** навешивается вызываемый метод:

```
item.MouseDoubleClick += MyMethod();
```

Затем, при определенных действиях пользователя все элементы списка очищаются и добавляются новые, с новыми значениями. Для них также добавляется событие двойного клика.

---

**Вопрос в том, удаляются ли старые слушатели вместе с элементами при удалении их через `ListView_.Items.Clear()`?**

Если нет, то как будет корректно их отсоединять? Есть ли в этом необходимость?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делегат удалится, но не сразу, а при сборке мусора. Это нормально.

Но я бы на вашем месте использовал `InputBindings` + `KeyBinding` с привязкой к команде. Чтобы вообще не думать о событиях.